# Lower bound of Gaussian tail?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Have $N$ denote a $N(0, 1)$ random variable. I have found a $K_1$ such that for all $x >0$,$$\textbf{P}(N \ge x) \le K_1 x^{-1} e^{-x^2/2}.$$My question is, does there exist $K_2 > 0$ such that for all $x \ge 1$,$$\textbf{P}(N \ge x) \ge K_2 x^{-1} e^{-x^2/2}\text{ ?}$$

Comment: What did you try? (And didn't you already post this recently?)

Comment: Hint: $x^{-1} e^{-x^2/2}$ increases without bound as $x \downarrow 0$. Can you figure out the answer to your question from this?

Comment: Without more constraints on $N$ we could have $P(N\ge 1)=0$ .Or if you want $P(N\ge x)>0 $ for $ x\ge 1$ ,we could have $0< P(N\ge x)< x^{-2} e^{-x^2/2}$ .In both cases $ K_2$  does not exist. Are you referring to the "Bell Curve"?  What is an $N(0,1)$ random variable?

Comment: Certainly the value of $K_1$ can serve in the role of $K_2$.  Perhaps your question is whether there is a value of $K_2$ that is less conservative than $K_1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a standard lower estimate for $1-\Phi(x) = P(N(0,1)\ge x)$: for all $x>0$,
$$
1-\Phi(x)> \frac{x}{x^2+1}\varphi(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
You can find the proof e.g. [here](http://www.johndcook.com/normalbounds.pdf).

So for $x\ge 1$ 
$$
1-\Phi(x)> \frac{1}{x+1/x}\varphi(x)\ge \frac{1}{2x}\varphi(x),
$$
consequently, the desired inequality holds with $K_2 = 1/(2\sqrt{2\pi})$.

Comment: for future visitors, it may help to know that this result is often known as "Mills' ratio". In Shorack's *Probability for Statisticians*, it is discussed in Exercise 6.1 (Mills' ratio), pg. 177, along with a slightly stronger one Shorack refers to as "Ito-McKean".